# Tricky Fourier Transfrom

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I stumbled upon a tricky Fourier Transform that I got stuck on:

$$ \textbf I(\textbf{x}) = \int \frac{d^dp}{(2\pi)^d}
~e^{ - i \textbf x \cdot \textbf p} \frac{-i \textbf p}{p^2}\delta^d(\textbf p),$$

where $\delta^D$ is a Dirac delta in $d-$dim.
Is the result simply $0$ for all $\textbf x$ or is there more to it?

P.S. I tried adding a $i \epsilon^2$ to the denominator (that gives zero in the limit $\epsilon \to 0$), but then the result changes if I add also something to the numerator... I'm confused.

Comment: How did you encounter this? Do you have reason to expect that it's well-defined?

Comment: An example would be the mean component of the force in electrostatics, produced by some charge distribution $\rho$. So in retrospect, it makes sense the net contribution is zero, but I wanted to be sure math works out as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will apply the standard techniques of quantum field theory.  Begin with,
$$
I^\mu(x^\mu) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu} \int \frac{d^dp}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{e^{-ix\cdot p} }{p^2} \delta^{(d)}(p).
$$
(I denote a vector with an index notation basically because I am used to that from physics.)  Introduce a so-called Schwinger parameterisation,
$$
I^\mu(x^\mu) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu} \int \frac{d^dp}{(2\pi)^d} \int_0^\infty d\tau e^{-ix\cdot p - \tau p^2} \delta^{(d)}(p).
$$
Interchange(!) the order of integration which allows one to use the $\delta$-function,
$$
I^\mu(x^\mu) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^d}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}\int_0^\infty d\tau=0.
$$
As is common with this technique, the integral is regularised to zero.  I have not checked in detail here but generally speaking: It is permitted to interchange the order of integrals by completing the square of the exponential and moving to spherical polar coordinates then analytically continuing $d$ into the complex plane.

Comment: Thanks for this. One small comment though, might it not make more sense to add an index on $I$ then, e.g. $I(x^\mu) \to I^\mu (x)$?

Comment: I have done that.  It appears the community does not agree on the normalisation of the momentum space $\delta$-function but it does not affect the final answer.